# Reading data from retrieved from server side before closing request

Tags: c#, jquery, xmlhttprequest, xmlwriter

In the following code I have **`tempGsContact`**  which is object takes it is value from a method, then I parse Into **`XML writer`** as shown. I need to get read each object retrieved to the client side without need to wait after all objects is finished. what could I do to achieve that ? I hope my question is clear !

```
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, xmlWriterSettings))
                {
     for (int count = 0; count < length - 1; count++)
      {
                tempGsContact = ConvertStringToContactObject(_fileContacts[count]);
               if (tempGsContact != null)
                {
                   tempGsContact.ContactSubInfo.Sort(new Comparison<GSContactInfo>((x, y)                 => string.Compare(x.ContactPropertyTitle, y.ContactPropertyTitle)));                                           
                 _fileContacts = null;
                   #region Convert Contact To XML Format                                            
                  xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Contact");
                  xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name", tempGsContact.DisplayName);
                  xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                  xmlWriter.Flush();
                  #endregion                                          
                }
       }
}
```

Comment: Why do you set `_fileContacts = null`?

Comment: coz I have to discard it is previous value !